# heroku redis mass insertion

Tags: heroku, redis

When working on my local machine i'm using this command for mass insertion:

```
cat fixtures.txt | redis-cli --pipe
```

but heroku gives a limited access to redis-cli, so I don't know how should I do it.

I tried:

```
heroku run "cat fixtures.txt | redis-cli --pipe"
```

resulting:

> bash: redis-cli: command not found

I tried:

```
cat fixtures.txt | heroku redis:cli --pipe
```

resulting:

> ▸    No Redis instances found.

Does anybody knows how to make it right?
I really need to initialize my redis with a lot of data

Comment: Have you tried specifying the heroku app? https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/heroku-redis#redis-cli

Comment: Yes, with the same response.
I can get to the redis command line with `heroku redis:cli`, my problem is how to initials it with a lot of data?